# SQL Server 2008 R2 set custom email alert output message

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on a table trigger that sends an email message `AFTER UPDATE`, I would like to change the output message from it's default "Mail queued", can this be done?

Here is an example of the code I'm using to send the email from my trigger:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name='SQLAlert'
    ,@recipients='billy.bob@rottentomatoes.com'
    ,@subject='Email Testing'
    ,@body='Get fresher tomatoes.'
```

The output message from this is **Mail queued.**

The reason I want to change this output message, is because an ERP software does the actual `INSERT` to my table, and if the email is sent in the trigger, a form appears in the ERP with the **Mail queued.** output message, I'd like to change it so the user has more information at their fingertips before reading the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @exclude_query_output=1 to disable the query execution messages.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name='SQLAlert'
,@recipients='billy.bob@rottentomatoes.com'
,@subject='Email Testing'
,@body='Get fresher tomatoes.'
,@exclude_query_output=1

print 'New Message you want Here'
```